# How to cast a subclass to a superclass [cannot convert]?

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, subclass, superclass

I have a general class called Hero and three subclasses that extends it: Mage, Warrior, Ranger. The Hero class has health and strength and each subclass has additional attributes.

```
public class Warrior extends Hero {
private int armor;

public Warrior(int health, int strength, int armor) {
    super(health,strength);
    this.armor = armor;
}

}


public class Hero {
private int health;
private int strength;

public Hero(int health, int strength) {
    this.health = health;
    this.strength = strength;

}

//Getters
public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}
public int strength() {
    return strength;
}
//Setters
public void takeDamage(Hero player, int n) {
    player.health = player.health-n;
}
public void healDamage(Hero player, int n) {
    player.health = player.health+n;
}
```

}

And in the main class I am trying to make two hero objects and when the user selects what class they want to be I want to create that hero class and cast it as a hero so it will have hero attributes and methods as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hero hero1 = new Hero(100,10);
    Hero hero2 = new Hero(100,10);
    //Players select the class
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Player select a class: Warrior, Mage, Ranger ");
    String p = scanner.next();
    switch (p) {
    case "Warrior": Warrior h1 = (Hero)hero1; //this doesn't work
        break;
    case "Mage":
        break;
    case "Ranger":
        break;
    }




}
```

I have looked around and I kind of understand in an example how an object may be an integer and you can do "int i = (Integer) object;". So I am confused as why my warrior who is a hero cannot be casted to a hero object.

Comment: class `Warrior` should extend `Here`

Comment: put the code of this classes :  `Mage`, `Warrior`, `Ranger`

Comment: *"my warrior who is a hero cannot be casted to a hero object"* You don't have a warrior, you have an arbitrary hero instance and you can't and shouldn't try to perform a downcast. If you wan't a warrior, then create one, instead of creating an instance of Hero and cast that.

Comment: [Creating specific objects based on user input](//stackoverflow.com/q/30022529)

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I copied the hero class twice instead of showing the warrior class. fixed now

Comment: If you didn't figure it out, I'd recommend you make Hero abstract: `public abstract class Hero`. This will prevent you from directly creating a Hero, but will allow you to create the subclasses, Warrior, Mage, and Ranger.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

`Hero hero1 = new Hero(100,10);`

You are saying that `hero1` is a `Hero`

Here:

`Warrior h1 = (Hero)hero1`

you are trying to say `hero1` is a `Warrior`, but it's not. It's a `Hero`.

The following is key: All `Warrior` instances are `Hero` instances, but not all `Hero` instances are a `Warrior`.

In order to cast `hero1` to a `Warrior`, it must be created as a `Warrior`. e.g.

`Hero hero1 = new Warrior(100,10);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you said below is a misconception:

> ... I want to create that hero class and cast it as a hero so it will have
>   hero attributes and methods as well.

Sub-classes always have properties of their super-class.  So in this case, if `Warrior` is a sub-class of `Hero`, then `Warrior` will have all properties and methods that `Hero` has, so you don't really need to "cast a sub-class to a super-class".  There is never such a need.

In this particular example, what you may want to write is either this

```
Hero hero1 = new Hero(100 /* health */,10 /* strength */);
. . .
case "Warrior": 
    Hero h1 = hero1; 
    break;
```

Or this

```
Hero warrior1 = new Warrior(100 /* health */
                            ,10 /* strength */
                            ,20 /* armor */);
. . .
case "Warrior": 
    Hero h1 = warrior1 ; 
    break;
```

Or even this

```
Warrior warrior1 = new Warrior(100 /* health */
                               ,10 /* strength */
                               ,20 /* armor */);
. . .
case "Warrior": 
    Hero h1 = warrior1 ; 
    break;
```

Which one is more appropriate? It depends on your exact situation (i.e. do you really want the object to be a `Hero` or a `Warrior`).

Comment: *"Which one is more appropriate?"* None of them, because they all use local variables with a rather limited scope.